# Try / Catch not displaying Exception error message

Tags: java, oop, try-catch, illegalargumentexception

Hey there so in my class I had written this:

```
public void setId(String id) { ...
    if (id.matches("[a-zA-Z]{3}-\\d{4}")) {
        this.id = id;
    } else { // id is invalid: exception occurs
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Inventory ID must be in the "
            + "form of ABC-1234");
    }

}
```

then in my main program I did this:

```
while (idLoopTrigger == true) {
        try {

            System.out.println("Please enter id: ");
            id = in.nextLine();

            if (id.matches("[a-zA-Z]{3}-\\d{4}")) {
                idLoopTrigger = false;
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            //print this error message out
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

        }

    }
```

So it will loop until the user inputs the correct info but it won't display the exception message from my class. Thoughts?

Comment: You don't call `setId()` anywhere in your loop.  No exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Does your code in the try block throws exception. Unless it throws it won't execute the catch block

Comment: You are not calling `setId()` anywhere, but you are actually testing every `id` from `nextLine`, so you never detect any invalid id that would throw the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're approximating the content of the `setId()` method in `main()` instead of calling it.

I'm not sure where this `setId()` method is supposed to live, but assuming it's defined in the same class as your `main()`:

```
while (idLoopTrigger == true) {

    try {
        System.out.println("Please enter id: ");
        id = in.nextLine();
        setId(id);
        idLoopTrigger = false;

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        //print this error message out
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

This seems to be at least close to what you're looking for.

Comment: that worked like a charm - thanks for the clarification!